# Changing linux date with current time

Tags: linux, time, date

I am running `sudo date +%m/%d/%Y -s 7/14/2010` command to change date. It changes fine except I want it to pick up the current time as well, and not start the time from 00:00:00 on 7/14/2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just extend the call to include hour information too:

```
sudo date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" -s "7/14/2010 10:00:00"
```

Comment: Perfect, i actually needed `sudo date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" -s "7/14/2010 `date +%T`"` but i didn't fully understand formats

Answer (score 2):

If you need accurate time, use ntpdate or better run ntpd daemon:

Example:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate clock.redhat.com
```

Answer (score 2):

It is often a good idea to sync the BIOS clock if there is that much of an offset after changing.  This can be done via:

`hwclock --systohc`

Typically distributions write to BIOS on a shutdown.

Comment: +1 I've gotten into the habit of doing this any time I set the date/time.